How can i send data from my forms to a summarypage in React?
I am currently learning react and I  want to send data from user input in my forms. I want the data to be collected on a new page. I also want the total price for my getCartTotal component to been shown up at the same page.
Do you have any tips for me?
here is my code so far :
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import { StoreComponent } from "../../components/StoreComponents";
import { Button } from "@mui/material";
import "../../styles/Order.css";

function Order() {
  const { getCartTotal } = useContext(StoreComponent);

  return (
    <form className="place-order">
      <div className="place-order-left">
        <p className="title">Delivery information</p>
        <div className="multi-fields">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Firstname"></input>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Lastname"></input>
        </div>
        <input type="email" placeholder="E-mail"></input>
        <div className="multi-fields">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Address"></input>
        </div>
        <div className="multi-fields">
          <input type="text" placeholder="zipcode"></input>
          <input type="text" placeholder="city"></input>
        </div>
        <input type="text" placeholder="phone"></input>
      </div>
      <div className="place-order-middle">
        <p className="title">Payment</p>
        <div className="multi-fields">
          <input type="text" placeholder="cardnumber"></input>
        </div>

        <div className="multi-fields">
          <input type="text" placeholder="expired"></input>
          <input type="text" placeholder="CVC-code"></input>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div className="place-order-right">
        <div className="cart-total">
          <h2>Cart Total</h2>
          <div>
            <div className="cart-totals-details">
              <p>Sum</p>
              <p>{getCartTotal()} $</p>
            </div>
            <hr></hr>
            <div className="cart-totals-details">
              <p>Fee</p>
              <p>{getCartTotal() === 0 ? 0 : 2} $</p>
            </div>
            <hr></hr>
            <div className="cart-totals-details">
              <b>Total</b>
              <b>{getCartTotal() === 0 ? 0 : getCartTotal() + 2} $</b>
            </div>
          </div>
          <Button variant="contained">Pay now</Button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  );
}

export default Order;


I am also new as well, here I have prepared a solution for you.
But I cannot explain things to you using exact industry terminologies.
However, I will expalin what is going around as my understanding.
import "./App.css";
import Home from "./components/Home";
import Child from "./components/FormComponent";
import Summary from "./components/SummaryComponent";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { useState } from "react";

function App() {


// declaring a state variable to hold the form data once the form is submitted.
//I dont think we can pass prop between two child components.
// so what we do is we pass the data to their immediate parent component 
//and then pass down from their to the next component.

  const [formData, setFormData] = useState("");

// This function is passed as prop to FormComponent,
//which then when we submit the will be called and will set the form data.

  const transferToSummaryComponent = (data) => {
    setFormData(data);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>App</h1>
      <Router>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/home" Component={Home} />
          <Route path="/child" element={<ChildComponent 
                  onSubmit={transferToSummaryComponent} />} />
              //function being passed as prop.
          <Route path="/summary" element={<SummaryComponent
                  data={childData} />} />
             //once form data is set, it is then passed as prop to needed component.
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;

    import React, { useState } from 'react'
    import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'
    
    const FormComponent = (props) => {
    
        const navigate = useNavigate();
    
    // to handle and hold the inputs given in forms.
        const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
            name: '',
            email: '',
            cartTotal: ''  //this is for total price or getCartTotal.
    //unlike other fields, this is not being retrieved from user input.
    // so we get a hold to this value a little differently. with a function below.
        })
    
    
    // function to get a hold to cartTotal.
        const calculateCartTotal = () => {
            return "$500";
    //this block can be replaced with your logic. For now i think it can be as:
    //  const { getCartTotal } = useContext(StoreComponent);
    //  return getCartTotal
    // not sure this will work. but if you can somehow retireve the value,
    // it will surely be passed to next component.
        };
    
    
    //Just handling input but notice cartTotal is being handled slightly differently.
        const handleInput = (e) => {
            const { name, value } = e.target;
            setFormData({ ...formData, [name]: value, cartTotal: calculateCartTotal() })
        }
    
    // handling the form submission. here, the function we passed from our
    //App.js is being called "props.onSubmit(formData".
    //Note: this 'onSubmit' is not related to form's onSubmit.
    //If in App.js we have onWhatever={transferToSummaryComponent} instead of
    //onSubmit={transferToSummaryComponent}, then it would be props.onWhatever(formData).
        const handleSubmit = (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            props.onSubmit(formData)    
    //function passed as prop from App.js is called which take the parameter, 
    //the state variable formData. Dont confuse this with formData of App.js.
    //They dont relate and work in their own components.
    // and when we call this function, it will go back to App.js and
    //perform whatever is written in its block which for now is setFormData(formData).
    //If in App.js our state variable was declared as, [receivedData, setReceivedData],
    //then we would have our function as
    //setReceivedData(whatever variable is declared in function defination.)
    
            navigate("/summary");
    // this will route you to next page. And since on this Route defination, we are passing
    //the receivedData(formData of App.js) as prop to the component
    //we can then receive the formData in the component and work with it as needed. 
        }
    
    
        return (
            <div>
                <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                    <input type='text'
                           name='name'
                           value={formData.name}
                           onChange={handleInput}></input>
                    <input type='text'
                           name='email'
                           value={formData.email}
                           onChange={handleInput}></input>
                    <button type='submit'>Send Data</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
    
    export default FormComponent



import React from 'react'

const SummaryComponent = ({ data }) => {    //received formData as prop.
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Data Of Child Component</h1>   // using them as needed
            <h2>Name: {data.name}</h2>
            <h2>email: {data.email}</h2>
            <h2>Total: {data.cartTotal}</h2>
        </div>
    )
}

export default SummaryComponent


The topic you're looking for is controlled input forms in React. The basic idea is to utilize hooks to maintain the form data. For example, in your case, you can create a new useState() hook and store an object with all the fields of the form. you can then pass this object as props to be rendered on any page.
Declare the object in the parent (depending on where you want to send data) using a useState() and then you can pass it around as props wherever required.
If you want I would be happy to write the codes or provides some reference material.
